# Jenkins job all time executes

Tags: powershell, jenkins, winrm

I have build step "Windows Powershell" in jenkins. In this step I run the next command:
winrs -r:hostname -username:name -password:pass "C:\Configuration\rights.ps1" 
This command run script which located on remote host using winrm. Script contain next strings:

```
$Acl = Get-Acl "C:\folder\test"
$Ar = New-Object  system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("IIS_IUSRS","FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl "C:\folder\test" $Acl

C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe Start Site test

Exit
```

After this command in output i see:
 powershell.exe "& 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson1559950339055289195.ps1'"
"test" successfully started.

And then i see executing icon and job not end but execute execute.
I think that problem was in PS script last string "Exit" but not(
Help me please!

Comment: You should add some debug output to help identify the code in trouble. Please provide more information.

Comment: Code works fine. Command C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe Start Site test have the next output: 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson1559950339055289195.ps1'" "test" successfully started.

Comment: I used:
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -credential $cred -ScriptBlock{}
instead:
winrs -r:hostname -username:name -password:pass "C:\Configuration\rights.ps1"
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -credential $cred -ScriptBlock{}
```

instead:

```
winrs -r:hostname -username:name -password:pass "C:\Configuration\rights.ps1"
```

Thanks guys!